# How to pass error argument to next line in Makefile

Tags: makefile

For example, a Makefile is as below. There is only one target "Test".
Because "open" is not a valid command, the first line will come into error. How could I transfer this error information to the following conditional directive?

```
Test:
    - open test.doc; ${foo} := $$?
ifeq (foo, 127)
    echo "there is a fault"
else    
    echo "why?"
endif
```

Comment: I believe `ifeq` are processed early, before executing targets. You need something else.

Comment: Additionally, shell variables in recipes are completely separate from `make` variables.  Shell code in recipes cannot assign values to `make` variables.

Answer (score 1):

By default, make will stop processing once a command return a non-zero status. You can change this by writing wrapper script, or by adding explicit SHELL commands to test the return code

```
Test:
    - open test.doc ; foo=$$? ; \
    if [ "$foo" = 127 ] ; then echo "There is a fault" ; else echo "Why ?" ; fi
```

Alternative:

```
Test:
    - open test.doc ; \
    if [ "$?" = 127 ] ; then echo "There is a fault" ; else echo "Why ?" ; fi
```